# Play-framework -What kind of value can be transmitted with a checkbox html?

Tags: html, playframework

I have a form where the user can choose different articles with a checkbox. I would like to transmit the article numbers of the checked articles, like so:

```
         <br><input type="checkbox" id="articleNr" name="articleNr"   value="${item.articleNr}" />${item.title}
```

My method in play returns me 0 for the article no, even though articles were checked:

```
    public static void addToX(double boardNr, double articleNr1){
                System.out.println("Article Nr: " + articleNr1);
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Put a debug point and check value of `request.params` 
See if the variable is there or not.

For checkboxes generally, if it is not checked, nothing gets submitted. Not sure how play handles it. It is is checked, you should be able to see a value in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is send if you check nothing, becareful by default when you checked the helper checkbox for play it is a boolean, if you use a standart input chekcbox nothing will be in the map of the request params :

Map< String, String[] > map = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
String[] checkedValue = map.get( "articleNr" );

it will be null if nothing is checked